# Minecraft Card Pack Random Generator

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to create a sort of trading card system in my minecraft world with command blocks. I just don't know to give the player 3 random cards from a set of cards with different levels of rarity. I can't use dispensers plus command blocks, because then you would have an equal chance of getting a common card as an extremely rare card. You would have to use a billion dispensers to get just the right ratios. I need a random generator, I have seen where you use the playOneMinute objective to get a sequence of very fast numbers that reset at 10 or whatever number, but if I were to draw 3 numbers, every second or so, they would be the same three numbers each time. (EX. If 3 were chosen, the same 2 numbers would come after it each time.) Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to do this yourself yet?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: @Vemonus yes, I have tried to solve this myself and I'm sorry I didn't pose an adequate question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

uou can do it by giving an invisible entity for example an invisible armor stand a point you can have armor stands with custom names like card 1 card 2 card 3 then it testfors for an armor stand that has a custom name like Card 2 then if it has a point then it will give the player a card

Answer (score -1):

If you need a RNG (Random Number Generator) you can build it with hoppers and redstone comparators. You can choose the best RNG for your needs [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Miscellaneous_circuits#Random_number_generator). But please don't forget, these RNGs use computer algorithms, making the RNG guessable, so please don't use the RNGs to generate passwords for websites.